# Java match counter and Pseudo match counter

Tags: java, arrays, match

I'm trying to make two methods, the other methods are running fine. The trouble is a pseudo match counter where an input should be the random number eg 5 4 3 2 and the user guess input eg 5 3 6 1 and the output would be: Pseudo match: 1 and matches: 2. I'm not understanding where I'm going wrong in my Pseudo Match method.

```
public int match(int[] guess) //Counts the number of matches
{
    int count = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<3; i++) 
    {
        if (lotteryNumbers[i] == guess[i])
        {
            count++;
        }

    }
    return count;
}
//First add psuedo counter for current program
//Then modify for multiple variables.

//Single slot to Single slot.
public int psuedoMatch(int[] guess)
{  
    boolean arraysEqual = true;
    int psuedoCount = 0;

    //Determine same size:
    if (lotteryNumbers.length != guess.length) 
    {
        arraysEqual = false;
    }

    //Determine if elements contain same data:

    while (arraysEqual && psuedoCount < 3) // guess.length
    {
        if (lotteryNumbers[psuedoCount] != guess[psuedoCount] )
        {
            arraysEqual = false;
        }
        psuedoCount++;
    }

    return psuedoCount;
}
```

Comment: we call this "bulls and cows" game =)

Comment: was my solution useful for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are trying to find the number of matches of these 2 arrays,
but the relative index of the equal elements should be different so that we can add them to the pseudo counter mechanism. So take a look at this method and try it:

```
public int psuedoMatch(int[] guess)
{
    int psuedoCount = 0;

    if (lotteryNumbers.length != guess.length)
        return 0;

    int size = lotteryNumbers.length;

    // Determine if elements contain same data, but at different indexes!

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            // Denote the inequality check i != j
            if (lotteryNumbers[i] == guess[j] && i != j)
                psuedoCount++;
        }
    }

    return psuedoCount;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm trying to do, thanks for your help! I'm just not understanding why there is a nested for loop.

Comment: @user1770068 nested for loop is used because you need to make a search in guess array for every element of lottery numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is what you are trying to do:

```
public int psuedoMatch(int[] guess) {          
    int psuedoCount = 0;

    //Determine same size:
    if (lotteryNumbers.length != guess.length) {
        return psuedoCount;
    }

    //Determine if elements contain same data:

    for(int i=0; i<lotteryNumbers.length || psuedoCount < 3; i++) {

        //I think you want to count all the matches till you have 3 matches
        if (lotteryNumbers[psuedoCount] == guess[psuedoCount]) {
            psuedoCount++;
        }            
    }

    return psuedoCount;
}
```